# .htaccess deny all files except one file which has a rewrite rule

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

actually I've a problem with my .htaccess file.
This is the Content of my .htaccess File:

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteRule ^put$ put.php 

Order Allow,Deny
<FilesMatch "^put\.php$">
Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

In the Folder where this file lays is also the file `put.php`.
I want to deny everything out of this folder, except `put.php` this file should be available at `domain.com/folder/put` nothing more.
But what it actually does, is that everything is denied, also `put` but `put.php` works. How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using just mod_rewrite. It could be that the filesmatch is denying the `/put` request, so mod_rewrite can't rewrite it.

Try:

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteRule ^put$ put.php [L]
RewriteRule !^put(\.php)?$ - [L,F]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /put\.php
RewriteRule ^put\.php$ - [L,F]
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, `put` and `put.php` are working correctly. But what can I do to make `put` working and `put.php` NOT working. Also it seems that all the other files are not reachable which is good! Thanks so far. :)